# osdev linker "file format not recognized"

Tags: makefile, x86, nasm, ld, osdev

I'm trying to make a simple OS, so I wrote a small kernel that consist out of a c file an assembly file that calls the main function in the c file.
but when I try to compile and link the two files together I get a `file format not recognized` error by the linker.

this is my Makefile:

```
BUILD?=build/
ASM?=nasm
ASMFLAGS?=-f obj
CC=i386-elf-gcc
LD=i386-elf-ld
CCFLAGS=-m32 -std=c11 -O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-aliasing
CCFLAGS+=-Wno-pointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter
CCFLAGS+=-nostdlib -nostdinc -ffreestanding -fno-pie -fno-stack-protector
CCFLAGS+=-fno-builtin-function -fno-builtin
LDFLAGS=

SOURCES_C=$(wildcard *.c)
SOURCES_ASM=$(wildcard *.asm)
OBJECTS_C=$(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD)/kernel/c/%.obj,$(SOURCES_C))
OBJECTS_ASM=$(patsubst %.asm,$(BUILD)/kernel/asm/%.obj,$(SOURCES_ASM))

all: kernel.bin

kernel.bin: $(OBJECTS_ASM) $(OBJECTS_C)
    $(LD) -o $(BUILD)/kernel.bin $< $(LDFLAGS) -Tlink.ld    

$(BUILD)/kernel/c/%.obj: %.c always
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(BUILD)/kernel/asm/%.obj: %.asm always
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

always:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD)/kernel/c
    mkdir -p $(BUILD)/kernel/asm
```

I also tried to change the `-f` flag in nasm to elf, but the I get a `undefined reference to main` error.

Here is my assembly file calling main:

```
[bits    32]
[extern main]

section .text
global _start
_start:
    call main
```

And my C file with the main function:

```
void main(){
    volatile char* video_memory = (volatile char*)0xb800;
    *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

So does anyone have an idea on what is causing the problem?

Comment: Using `-f elf32` with NASM would be correct here since the default is to use `-f bin` which the linker can't handle thus the error. Undefined reference to main - can you show us you ASM file? Is `main` being called from your assembly code? If it is, do you have a main defined in your C files?

Comment: What I didn't notice before is that your compiler flags `CCFLAGS` is missing `-c`. Without `-c` you are compiling each C file to an executable and then linking the executables to a binary. Use `-c` to compile to actual object files.

Comment: yes, I thought that I did something wrong building my cross compiler, so I built it again and it took some time. But it turns out it was the -c flag in gcc. Thank you so much!